# TFS 2017 anti-virus exclusion

Tags: team-foundation-server, anti-virus

Does anyone know if there is an official anti-virus exclusion list from Microsoft that lists which folders and processes should be excluded from anti-virus on the TFS 2017 application server?

This one is for TFS 2015 which I found a long time ago:
Processes to be excluded:

1. w3wp.exe process present in the location: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
2. TFSJobAgent.exe present in the location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\TFSJobAgent.exe

Folders to be excluded:

1. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin
2. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data
3. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
4. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
5. C:\inetpub\temp
6. D:\TfsData\ApplicationTier_fileCache
7. C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Temp
8. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14

Is there such a list for TFS 2017 on-premises server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no updated list then the list has not changed. I dont believe there has been significant structural change since 2015, so i would go with this list.

Comment: @chicks, that's the answer, not a question.

Comment: OK, sorry for misreading it.  I still think some links or official authority would help here.

Comment: Already covered in the question. But ok...

Answer (score 0):

For an Azure DevOps build server I found these exclusions

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#anti-virus-exclusion